# Linker error - multiple definition of a variable not multiply defined

Tags: gcc, linker-errors

I have three files: src/dsm.c include/dsm.h and apps/convolution.c

include/dsm.h

```
#ifndef __DSM_HEADER_GUARD
#define __DSM_HEADER_GUARD

... inclusions ...

/* Number of nodes */
int P;

... variable, struct, and function declarations ...
#endif
```

src/dsm.c:

```
#include "../include/dsm.h"
...
function implementations using P
...
```

apps/convolution.c

```
#include "../include/dsm.h"
... functions including a main function, using P ...
```

I compile this with the commands

```
mpicc.mpich -O3 -g -Wall -ffast-math -c src/dsm.c -o obj/dsm.o
```

which works, and then

```
mpicc.mpich -O3 -g -Wall -ffast-math apps/convolution.c obj/dsm.o -o bin/convolution
```

which fails with multiple definition errors

usr/bin/ld: obj/dsm.o:/home/thomas/work/dsm/library/src/../include/dsm.h:24: multiple definition of `P'; /tmp/cchjN5xx.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

P is not in fact defined multiple times, as verified with a grep on int P. Also if I comment out the declaration, the compiler changes the error to P not being defined.

What could be causing this? Is it helpful for me to upload the full code (about 400 lines)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a common issue regarding global variables defined in headers. In the header file, you need to declare (not define) the variable using `extern int P;`. Then in exactly one ".c" file, you define it as normal (namely `int P;`).

As for the reason, note that I may not be correct on this, but I think it's because while compiling the two ".c" files separately, the definition in the header is included in both resultant ".o" files (the guard doesn't work since the two compilations are independent to each other), which leads to duplication during linking.